# 500 error while calling Web API with XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-web-api

I developed a web api in .net 4.5.  When I test the api call, I am getting a 500 error.  This behavior only happens when I send in XML.  If I use JSON of Form URL encoded string the server handles the request properly.

I added

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

to the WebApiConfig.cs and the error returned is:

```
<Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException</ExceptionType><StackTrace>   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.&lt;InvokeActionWithExceptionFilters&gt;d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
  at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.&lt;SendAsync&gt;d__0.MoveNext()</StackTrace></Error>
```

My header are:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Host: corebeta.pexcard.com
Content-Length: 119
```

My request is:

```
<Admin.CardListRequest>
<username>TestUser</username>
<password>GoodPassword</password>
</Admin.CardListRequest>
```

My class looks like this:

```
public class CardListRequest{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The WebAPI code looks like this(log is using log4net, and nothing is written to that log):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the list of open cardholders
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="UserName">The username you use to log on to pexcardadmin.com</param>
    /// <param name="Password">The password you use to log on to pexcardadmin.com</param>
    /// <returns>A list of cardholders with balances</returns>
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Admin.Account> CardList(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        try
        {

            log.Info(String.Format("Admin Parameters: <UserName={0}>", UserName));
            AuthenticateApi(UserName, Password, "cardList");
            var Ret = GetCoreCardCardList(UserName, Password);
            APIData.Response = "Success";


            return Ret;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Error(e);
            APIData.Response = e.Message;
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            APIData.ResponseTime = DateTime.Now;
            APILog.LogAPI(APIData);
        }

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the list of open cardholders
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Req"> The Request Parameter</param>
    /// <returns>A list of cardholders with balances</returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public List<Admin.Account> CardList(Admin.CardListRequest Req)
    {
        APIData.ParamBlob = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Req);
        return CardList(Req.UserName, Req.Password);

    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why this error is being thrown?

Thanks,
Steven

Comment: show your web api code that handles the request

Comment: I have added my code to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by ensuring that that the XML is correct.  To do this I created a new web api function that had the return type I wanted and with the fields I wanted filled in, and used that exact response to send into the web api.